# Injected service in a component from other module is null

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have an angular v6 project that contains 2 modules, the app.module.ts that contains the AppComponent and a BoatComponet, it also imports another module draggable.module.ts.

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BoatComponent    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    DraggableModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

draggable.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    OverlayModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    DraggableDirective,
    DropzoneDirective,
  ],
  exports: [
    DraggableDirective,    
    DropzoneDirective,
  ],
  providers: [
    DroppableService
  ]
})
export class DraggableModule { }
```

This DraggableModule contains a service called DroppableService that I want to inject in the BoatComponent (defined in the main module)

droppable.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DroppableService {
  dragStart$: Observable<PointerEvent>;
  dragEnd$: Observable<PointerEvent>;
  dragMove$: Observable<DraggingBoat>;  

  private dragStartSubject = new Subject<PointerEvent>();
  private dragEndSubject = new Subject<PointerEvent>();
  private dragMoveSubject = new Subject<DraggingBoat>();  

  constructor(@SkipSelf() @Optional() private parent?: DroppableService) {
    console.log('droppable service has been created!');
    this.dragStart$ = this.dragStartSubject.asObservable();
    this.dragEnd$ = this.dragEndSubject.asObservable();
    this.dragMove$ = this.dragMoveSubject.asObservable();    
  }

  onDragStart(event: PointerEvent) {
    this.dragStartSubject.next(event);

    if (this.parent) {
      this.parent.onDragStart(event);
    }
  }
}
```

boat.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-boat',
  templateUrl: './boat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./boat.component.scss']
})

export class BoatComponent {

  constructor(public element: ElementRef,
    private droppableService: DroppableService) {    
  }

    @HostListener('document:pointermove', ['$event'])
    onPointerMove(event: PointerEvent): void {
        if (!this.dragging) {
          return;
        }

        const clientRect = this.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        const draggingBoat: DraggingBoat = {
          objectRect: {
            top: Math.round(event.clientY - this.startPosition.y),
            bottom: Math.round(event.clientY - this.startPosition.y + clientRect.bottom - clientRect.top),
            left: Math.round(event.clientX - this.startPosition.x),
            right: Math.round(event.clientX - this.startPosition.x + clientRect.right - clientRect.left)
          },
          pointerEvent: event
        };

        this.droppableService.onDragMove(draggingBoat);   
    }
}
```

I am experiencing a "cannot read property 'onDragMove' of undefined". 
Why? Is this possible?

Comment: Can you show the function that contains that line please? It may be because the context of `this` is not what you're expecting

Comment: I have updated the function

Comment: you must provide your service at higher module i.e appModule, then the service should be accessible to both of your modules

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. It is not related with the service. Basically I have another Component that extends the BoatComponent and was not passing the service in the construnctor and in the super. This was not visible in the question because I never thought about it!

```
export class SpecificBoatComponent extends BoatComponent {
  constructor(public element: ElementRef, droppableService: DroppableService) {
    super(element, droppableService);
  }
}
```

Just added another parameter in there.